# Transformation of any List to List<Object[]>

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I want to be able to transform any List<> to the List of Object[] - i.e. every element of the given list should be transformed to Object array in a given way.

For example, I have

```
List<User> users = 
        Lists.newArrayList(new User((long) 1, "Name1"), new User ((long) 2, "Name2"));
```

and a Function

```
Function <User, Object[]> mapper = 
                           user -> new Object[] {user.getUserId(), user.getUserName()}
```

And I need to get List of Object arrays, by transforming every user with the mapper. But the point is to write the function, that can work with any given list and any given mapper.

I created Transformer class and tried to achieve my goal in the next way, but got compilation error:

```
class Transformer {    
    private List<?> content;
    private Function<?, Object[]> mapper; 
    //getters and setters
    ....
    public List<Object[]> transform() {
        return content.stream()
                      .map(mapper)   // this row isn't compiled
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}



Error:(75, 45) java: method map in interface java.util.stream.Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types; 
required: java.util.function.Function<? super capture#1 of ?,? extends R> 
found: java.util.function.Function<capture#2 of ?,java.lang.Object[]> 
reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R 
(argument mismatch; java.util.function.Function<capture#2 of ?,java.lang.Object[]> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Function<? super capture#1 of ?,? extends R>)
```

What advice can you give me?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Error:(75, 45) java: method map in interface java.util.stream.Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Function<? super capture#1 of ?,? extends R>
  found: java.util.function.Function<capture#2 of ?,java.lang.Object[]>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (argument mismatch; java.util.function.Function<capture#2 of ?,java.lang.Object[]> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Function<? super capture#1 of ?,? extends R>)

Comment: @funny-funny Don't post this as comment. This information is relevant to question so you should [edit] it and include this information there.

Comment: @Pshemo added error's text to the question.

Comment: @funny-funny Good job. Now consider posting it in a form you got it, which was most probably formatted in a way that it could be easily read, instead of being wall of text.

Comment: Anyway I suspect that instead of separate `Transformer` class you need one method like `public static <T> List<Object[]> transform(List<T> content, Function <T, Object[]> mapper) {...}`. Or if you really need separate class then make it generic `class Transformer<T>{...}` with `List<T> content` and `Function<T, Object[]> mapper` fields.

Comment: @Pshemo is there any way to avoid using generics? And the option with method with 2 arguments isn't also good for me, because it's necessary for transform method to be without arguments.

Comment: You can avoid generics by using explicit type `List<User>` instead of `List<?>` or `List<T>` but judging by this request your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so maybe consider telling us more about your requirements.

Comment: I've told the reason of avoiding generics in the comment to the answer from Louis Wasserman

Comment: @funny-funny Reason you mentioned there is in fact in favour of using generic types. Anyway if you want to avoid creating many objects of Transformer class and you want it to be able to handle lists of many types based on Function you used then generic method seems like best solution. Like I said, your question is not very clear. Consider updating your post with pseudo-code example of how you would like to use Transformer class. Then we can discuss how you can solve it or explain why it can't be done and give you some alternative solutions (which most probably will be generic methods/classes).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Transformer {    
  private List<?> content;
  private Function<?, Object[]> mapper;
```

You really can't use wildcards like this.  You really do need to write something that looks like

```
class Transformer<T> {
  private List<T> content;
  private Function<T, Object[]> mapper;
```

...although for what it's worth, using `Object[]` like you're using here is a serious design smell.

Comment: Add a space to fix code formatting; remove one 'm' from 'smmell'.  (That's only two characters so I can't fix it for you.)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using generic class?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using a generic class?  That's how you get type safety.

Comment: Because I want to be able to use one Transformer object for transforming different classes, simply changing the content and mapper by setters.

Comment: There's not going to be a way to do that type-safely.  Why do you want to use only one `Transformer` object?  They're not going to be expensive.